# Convert number from 002541500(Last 4 digits are decimal places) to 254.1500 using sql server

Tags: sql-server

Convert number from 002541500(Last 4 digits are decimal places) to 254.1500 in sql server

Comment: Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you asking how to divide with 10000 ?

Answer (score 2):

This is simple maths:

```
CONVERT(int,Yourcolumn) / 10000.00
```

If you have to have 4 decimal places, use CONVERT:

```
CONVERT(decimal(10,4), CONVERT(int,YourColumn) / 10000.00)
```

Comment: This solution will return error. Try this with input @imp_ori varchar(50) = '00251500'.  you need first to convert and then to do math

Comment: @Larnu you can with decimal. Not with float though

Comment: @Larnu/@t-clausen.dk , there is no issue (except the basic idea that this is poor code and not recommended) to use implicit convert to decimal or to float. unfortunately the poor interface in stackoverflow does not allow me to post code in the comment. I really don't like stackoverflow interface... anyhow try this declare variable as varchar(50) = '10254.1500' and now declare variable as decimal(9,4) with the value 1. next you can use "select @i/@d" and the server will implicit convert the string to decimal (same with  float if you declare the second variable to float)

Comment: @RonenAriely you can post inline code in a comment. encapsulate your text in backticks (`\``).

Comment: I think that there is small funny/sad case here: we had a discussion where I explained why the original answer was wrong. Unfortunately, the interface here gives the option to edit the answer after we had a discussion about it, which lead to a small funny/sad case! The comments become irrelevant and now people start to flag comment as abusive since they say the answer is wrong (which was correct at the time the comment was written)! and the answer which was changed get new voting and jump to the top instead of other answers which were correct.

Comment: Awesome @Larnu :-) thanks for the comment. I am not coming here a lot so I am not familiar with the system well. (
thanks for the way to add code
but will several lines works?
I try here)

Comment: code do not work for me in the comment. I am missing something probably (`  test 02 code in comment without line break  `)

Comment: OK I got how to add inline code which does not help since there is no option to add multi line code, but thanks for helping me learn something new:-) `Here is code in comment without line break`

Comment: @RonenAriely No, you can't add multiline code; all comments are inline (which is why i mentioned you can put "inline" code :) ). As for when putting code, you have to put it directly on either side. \`SELECT 1;\` would appear as code (I've escaped those back ticks) where as ` SELECT 1; ` does not (no escaping).

Comment: To clarify, @Larnu's answer was wrong originally and the comments are related to the original version as can be seen here:https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51043159/revisions. For some reason the comment that thanks my comments for example, were removed and the original answer was changed according to my comments, which change the history! Unfortunately, this behavior made my comments become irrelevant and look bad, and users that come after the change of history voted for the fixed answer while un-vote for the answer which was correct from the start. sry you cannot see the entire discussion now

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @i varchar(50) = '00251500' 
--Option 1:
select convert(decimal(9,4), CONVERT(int, @i) / 10000.00)
```

Comment: So you complain about the comments and posting habits of others yet you post a code-only response with no explanation. It is not reasonable to expect someone to root through the sequence of comments that you have made to figure out why you think this approach is better.

Comment: Please read my comment about the issue in this interface. Your comment shows exactly what I am talking about! I did not said that my approach is better THIS WAS THE ONLY SOLUTION in the thread since the other one was a mistake. AFTER I PUBLISHED THIS ANSWER THE OTHER USER FIXED HIS ANSWER according to my comment on his original answer! this is the issue I mean. I would not publish another answer if there was a good answer before OR I WOULD SAY WHY THIS IS BETTER IN MY OPINION but this is not the case. This was not better BUT THE ONLY GOOD ANSWER at the time I published it :-)

Comment: and now I see that even the voting it got before are down to zero voting! I really hat this interface more and more each time I test it. The option to change the history make people like you @SMor that come too late, and they get wrong conclusion about what you see here, since they do not see the right history! If I would see late answer which is the same as the first I would also think that this has not place maybe, BUT YOU FORGET THAT AT THE TIME I PUBLISHED MY ANSWER, THERE WAS NO OTHER GOOD ANSWER! and the answer that was here before raised errors since it was wrong!.

Answer (score 0):

By multiplying the varchar with 1, the basetype gets converted to numeric. By multiplying this result with .0001 the scale changes from 0 to 4.

```
SELECT 1 * '902541501' * .0001
```

Result

```
90254.1501
```

[SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY_TSQL);k(sql13.swb.tsqlresults.f1);k(sql13.swb.tsqlquery.f1);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true):

```
SELECT 
  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(1 * '902541501' * .0001, 'BaseType') BaseType,
  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(1 * '902541501' * .0001, 'Scale') Scale
```

Result

```
BaseType   Scale
numeric    4
```

Comment: Hi @t-clausen.dk, please try this using your approach in the answer: `SELECT 1 * '09025415001' * .0001` Almost always I HIGHLY recommend to use explicit convert to avoid un-expected results. Using explicit convert we can use for example BIGINT if needed instead of INT in places that the server try to implicitly convert to INT. With that being said this solution fit the for INT :-)

Answer (score -1):

I found the way to fix the issue

```
declare @imp_ori varchar(50) = '00251500' 
select 
cast(left(@imp_ori,4) + '.' + right(@imp_ori,4) as numeric(10,4)) as StringBuildCast
```

> result: 25.1500

Comment: That is excessively complicated for a simple / 10000.

Comment: This will not work on your sample data in the question. it will return 0025.1500
 Instead of 254.1500